# unrelated if statement removes value

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-blade

i have an issue with the first if statement in the class. it handles if the popup(livewire) is shown or not.
it also ONLY removes the amount that is shown with `$details->amount` later in the code. The rest of the details is shown

when i remove the if statement it shows the amount correctly

```
<section class="
@if (!$showModal)hidden @endif 
fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-end bg-black bg-opacity-50">
        <div wire:click.away="toggleShow" class="bg-white w-2/4 h-full p-4">
            <header class="flex justify-between items-center mb-5">
                <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold text-black mb-1">Order</h2>
    
                <p class="cursor-pointer" wire:click="toggleShow">
                    <x-button>X</x-button>
                </p>
            </header>
            <section class="bg-yellow overflow-y-auto h-full pb-8">
                <aside class="flex flex-wrap">

                    @if($cartItems)
                        @foreach ($cartItems as $details)
                            <div class="flex flex-col justify-center w-72 h-72 mt-6 mx-7 bg-brightyellow bg-opacity-50 rounded-lg"> 
                                <div class="w-full mt-[-28] ml-2 bg-opacity-100 flex justify-end">
                                    <button wire:click="removeFromOrder({{$details->id}})" class="w-5 h-5 bg-[#dc2222] rounded-full text-xs text-white flex items-center justify-center">
                                        X
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <img class="object-contain h-48 p-4" src={{$details->image}} alt="">  
                                <div class="mx-auto justify-center">
                                    <p>Product: {{$details->name}}</p>   
                                    <h3>€{{number_format($details->price, 2)}}</h3>
                                    
                                    <p>amount: {{$details->amount}}</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach

                        <div class="fixed bottom-20 right-10 px-2 py-2 rounded-lg bg-brightyellow bg-opacity-50">
                            <p class="text-xl">Totaal: €{{number_format($total, 2)}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <x-button wire:click="confirmOrder" class="fixed bottom-10 right-10">confirm</x-button>
                    @else
                        <div class="flex flex-col justify-center w-72 h-72 mt-6 mx-7 bg-brightyellow bg-opacity-50 rounded-lg"> 
                            <p class="text-darkyellow flex justify-center">No items</p>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                </aside>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
```

i have checked if amount is filled.

it is show when leaving out the if statement in the class.

i would show images but im not allowed yet

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only `if` statement you have in you code is setting a `hidden` class to your `<section>`, which (probably?) makes all content in that `<section>` hidden, then I wouldn't expect to see _any_ of the content, including `<p>amount: {{ $details->amount }}</p>`. If that's not what you mean, then you'll probably need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77574244/edit) and explain your issue a bit more clearly.

Comment: hi i changed is so it is maybe more understandable.     i wanted to show an image of what i mean but im not allowed to do so

Comment: Yeah, that's one of Stackoverflow's limitations on new users... You can include the image as a link (which should be generated when you click the `Insert Image` button when editing your question), and someone with more reputation (i.e. myself) can edit the question to include the image as an actual image.

Comment: ok, i have done that

Comment: fixed it. had something to do with a count check i was calling when pressing X, but forgot to put it on the cart itself too. thanks for the help!